# Running Google Workflows in Parallel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-workflows

I have a collection of documents in cloud firestore, every night I would like to run Workflows on each document to perform a series of transformations. The transformation of one document has no effect on another. I currently have a for loop in my YAML file that does the transformation of each document one at a time. I was wondering if I can perform the transformation to all the documents in parallel instead of one at a time.

Comment: Parallel steps (including parallel for loops) is launching in 1-2 weeks (I'm the PM). Until then, there's experimental.executions.map: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/map

Comment: I appreciate the heads up! thank you. Also, do you know how I can avoid a workflows timeout when running a long Cloud-run operation?

Comment: You can increase the timeout to 1800 (30 minutes): https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/http-requests

If you need longer, Cloud Run Jobs might be a better solution: 
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs (and see the connector for Workflows: 
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/namespaces.jobs/run)

Comment: Thank you, Kris. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kris, I have the workflow timeout for 1800s but my cloud run is 3600s - how can I make workflows operate with a long-running cloud run instance?

Comment: 1800 (30 minutes) is the current limit for synchronous HTTP requests. For longer jobs, consider Cloud Run Jobs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs

Comment: Thanks Kris, how would I invoke the Cloud Run Jobs from workflows? Wouldn't it still be an HTTP request? I'm chaining microservices but one service, in particular, takes 30+ minutes ( the remaining services depend on the results of the long-running service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflow steps can be done in parallel:

https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/parallel-steps#example_of_parallel_branches

Code snippet:

```yaml
main:
  params: [args]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - user: {}
          - notification: {}
    - parallelStep:
        parallel:
          shared: [user, notification]
          branches:
            - getUser:
                steps:
                  - getUserCall:
                      call: http.get
                      args:
                        url: ${"https://example.com/users/" + args.userId}
                      result: user
            - getNotification:
                steps:
                  - getNotificationCall:
                      call: http.get
                      args:
                        url: ${"https://example.com/notification/" + args.notificationId}
                      result: notification
```